# How to get all the values of same class name in one line in bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have scrape the data from a website, and it has variant images with same class name. My piece of code is this

```
images = soup.find_all('div' , {"class" : "slim-slide zoom"})
    listings = []
    for image in images:      
      try:
        variant_image = image.find('img' , {"class" : "zoom-image"})["src"].replace("\n",",")
        listings.append(image.get_text(strip=True))
      except AttributeError:
        variant_image = 'NA'
      print(variant_image)
```

And I am getting the output like this

```
https://pa.namshicdn.com/product/A8/42187W/1-zoom-desktop.jpg
https://pa.namshicdn.com/product/A8/42187W/2-zoom-desktop.jpg
https://pa.namshicdn.com/product/A8/42187W/3-zoom-desktop.jpg
https://pa.namshicdn.com/product/A8/42187W/4-zoom-desktop.jpg
https://pa.namshicdn.com/product/A8/42187W/5-zoom-desktop.jpg
https://pa.namshicdn.com/product/A8/42187W/6-zoom-desktop.jpg
https://pa.namshicdn.com/product/A8/42187W/7-zoom-desktop.jpg
https://pa.namshicdn.com/product/A8/42187W/8-zoom-desktop.jpg
```

How can I get all these values in single line. Separated by comma.

When I am writing in a csv file, then for each link a new row is made with repeating all other columns values.

Please tell me how can I make in single line

Thank you

Comment: try with `print(variant_image,end=",") `

Answer (score 1):

Use join that will take your array and combine the elements. Simply denote that you want a comma.

```
images = soup.find_all('div' , {"class" : "slim-slide zoom"})
    listings = []
    for image in images:      
      try:
        variant_image = image.find('img' , {"class" : "zoom-image"})["src"].replace("\n",",")
        listings.append(image.get_text(strip=True))
      except AttributeError:
        variant_image = 'NA'
      print(variant_image)

    combined = ','.join(listings)
```